# How to apply compound styles to curves in e.g. Plot

Tags: plotting, graphics, options

Say, I have a colorlist

```
listColor={Black,Brown,Red,Cyan}
```

Now, I have some `Plot` function that I can use this list:

```
Plot[{Sin[x],Cos[x],x,x^2},{x,1,100},PlotStyle->listColor]
```

Everything went fine. Now, I wanted to make the plot style "thick"

But when I add:

```
Plot[{Sin[x],Cos[x],x,x^2},{x,1,100},PlotStyle->{Thick,listColor}]
```

The listColor breaks down. I understand I actually need

```
listColor={{Thick, Black},{Thick, Brown},{Thick, Red},{Thick, Cyan}}
```

But adding {Thick} to each entry of listColor is too hard. Is there anyway that I can append {Thick, } to each entry of the list elegantly?

I notice that using

```
Transpose[{Table[Thick,{i,1,4}],listColor}]
```

might work but it looks unnecessary...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `BaseStyle` for some of directives:

```
listColor = {Black, Brown, Red, Cyan}
Plot[{Sin[x], Cos[x], x, x^2}, {x, 0, 1}, PlotStyle -> listColor, BaseStyle -> Thick]
```

[image]

Another way is to use all in `PlotStyle`:

```
PlotStyle -> Thread[Directive[listColor, Thick]] (*or just*)
PlotStyle -> Thread[{listColor, Thick}] (* or using your approach:*)
PlotStyle -> Table[{Thick, i}, {i, listColor}]
```